# SVN fetch of what was updated

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am creating a tool that monitors what was updated in SVN (via Tortoise) and then does actions based on that content.

I can use post update hooks to get the latest revision number, but if there were no new updates, then I still see that revision number anyway.

Is there a way to find out what revisions were accessed for the first time in the last update?

Comment: Please clarify. Exactly what are you trying to do? How does a post-commit hook have anything to do with it? Is the user attempting to see whether they need to update their working directory? Are you trying to synchronize another repository of some sort? Is your tool something that runs only when new stuff is in the repository?

Comment: We have database scripts coming through in our updates that need to be run against our local db's. I am trying to detect when the updates include scripts created elsewhere and run our special update tool. I said "post-update" not "post-commit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have database scripts coming through in our updates that need to be run against our local db's. I am trying to detect when the updates include scripts created elsewhere and run our special update tool.

I suggest you look at [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org). Jenkins is a continuous build system and is designed to do a *build* every time someone commits code. What Jenkins actually does in a *build* is up to you. Jenkins can run almost any sort of build script (Makefiles, Ant, MSBuild, and even batch and shell scripts) when triggered. It can do pre-build actions and post-build actions. It can trigger one build after another build is complete.

Jenkins has dozens of [plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins) which can help extend Jenkins.

The big thing is that Jenkins can pass onto your scripts useful information such a the Subversion revision number that triggered the build. From there, you can parse the output of the `svn log` to find the names of the files that were changed, and handle them appropriately.

Jenkins is easy to learn and easy to install. You can use it on Windows, Mac, Linux, Solaris, or almost any computer that can run Java 1.6. On Windows, the installation program includes the Java 1.6 run time and installs itself as a Windows service.

Comment: Is that client-side or server-side?  My need is client-side.

Comment: Are you saying these are databases local to the user? Are you using the TortoiseSVN hooks? It's dangerous practice to depend upon TortoiseSVN hooks on a site wide basis because each client must be configured, the hooks must be on the local user machine, and there's no guarantee that someone is using the ToroiseSVN client or has it configured with the hooks.

Comment: Currently the developers are doing the local updates manually, so I'm looking to improve that process.  Back to the question - does Jenkins support client-side?

Comment: Jenkins doesn't do client side updates.